# WTForms is trying to read my tuples as SQLAlchemy row objects and throwing an error

Tags: python, integer, tuples, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to write an app that will allow a user to view a playlist, and then add songs to the playlist (only if the song is not already on the playlist). I am using SQLAlchemy and WTForms inside of Flask to do this.

My code for the app route is:

```
playlist = Playlist.query.get_or_404(playlist_id)
    form = NewSongForPlaylistForm()


    curr_on_playlist = [s.id for s in playlist.songs]
    choices = (db.session.query(Song.id, Song.title).filter(Song.id.notin_(curr_on_playlist)).all())
    
    for choice in choices:
        choice = tuple(choice)
        print(type(choice), "*****************************")
        print(type(choices[0]))
```

The prints let me know that right after the choice is assigned to become a tuple, it shows as a tuple, but when the next line runs (to print the 0-index choice in the choices list), it gets returned as a sqlalchemy row object.

This is an issue because it tries to pass the row object as the sole value (instead of seeing it as a tuple with a value and a label). In turn, because I have coerce 'int' in the WTForms field:

```
class NewSongForPlaylistForm(FlaskForm):
    """Form for adding a song to playlist."""

    song = SelectField('Song To Add', coerce=int)
```

When I take the coerce=int away, the form fills properly, but each entry is rendered in the HTML as such:

```
<option value="(1, 'learning to fly')">(1, 'learning to fly')</option>
<option value="(2, 'learning to fly')">(2, 'learning to fly')</option>
```

rather than splitting the tuple into the integer value and the string label.

Does anybody understand why the tuples are becoming rows again? Furthermore, how do I make them stay tuples? Shouldn't they already be tuples? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension should help out:

```
curr_on_playlist = [s.id for s in playlist.songs]
result = (db.session.query(Song.id, Song.title).filter(Song.id.notin_(curr_on_playlist)).all())
choices = [(x.id, x.title) for x in result]
```

Now choices will be a list of tuples `[(1, 'Example'), (2, 'Other')]` which `wtforms` should be happy to deal with.

On another note-- you should probably be looking into the `from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm import QuerySelectField` which will let you just deal with the SQLAlchemy model directly, and not have to convert to and from int's.